# GITHUB is Pushing the changes with Old Credentials not with New Credentials

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, github, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have recently configured GITHUB with Visual Studio 2013 Express with Demo GITHub account i.e. for practice purpose.

> **Good News is that** : I have configured it properly
>
> **But Problem is :**
>
> When I am trying to configure with Genuine Account at GITHub, Visual
> Studio is not pushing the solution at Genuine Repository.

After a-lot of research, it appears that when I am Pushing the solution...
**Visual Studio is trying to push it by my Demo Git Account.**

> As my Visual Studio is not asking to insert New User Name and
> Password, I want to know how can I change it.
>
> I have tried the same of my another system, with actual User name and
> Password...and it is working fine there.

**Please suggest, how to remove my Demo User Name and Password and Login via New Credentials.**

Comment: Realizing there is a difference between **Git** and **GitHub**, please be a bit more specific about what you are doing.  "Pushing" would be a Git operation **to** a repository on **GitHub**, but requires the proper credentials for that account.

Comment: Hi Thom Parkin, Actually I am using VS2013, so for the first time when we connect GitHub to Push the changes, it asks for credentials but afterward that, VS2013 saves the details. My Problem is that : when I am trying to connect with other GitHub Account, it is not prompting up for New credentials, instead of that, it is using old one. So I need to know how to remove old credentials with new one.

Answer (score 7):

In order to change the stored credentials for `VS2013`; to commit or clone to a new GIT server, Navigate to:

`control panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager`

There you should see the git credentials that were used on previous projects.

Comment: Not sure if the OP found his or her answer, but this worked for me and I am now in `VS2015`.